# How to make ios applications run in background and foreground on events

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am having an application that will listen to sounds ans it will give some messages on their frequencies.The program uses iphone microphone for listening.

I want now to run this in background and popup only when a particular event occurs. Is there a way to do this.So i need not to run the app in foreground always.Only when an event occurs it should come to foreground.

Comment: without user interaction application can't come to foreground.

Comment: if am checking for a particular frequency value in my code.On detecting a particular frequency it is doing some outputs.Can i make the program come to foreground programatically..@Rushabh Or is there a way to give some notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App couldn't bring itself to foreground. Only user could do it.
But you could use Local Notifications. User will see banner or alert and if he taps on it then app will bring to foreground. For example:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.alertBody = @"Event occurs";
notification.alertAction = @"Open";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can but your application will be only half-background. Like when you call someone and do something else at the same time (with the greenbar behind).

But it doesn't mean you can suddenly make your apps pop in front of the user. You can display him a message in the temporary header then he can tap on it.

I suggest you to read [Background Execution and Multitasking - Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple%5fref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24) Then go to the section : *Playing and Recording Background Audio*